# Почему Провайдер презентера находится в активити модуле

Tags: android, mvp, dagger2

Нашел на гитхабе  [проект](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvp-architecture), который представлен как эталон реализации MVP с Dagger 2.   Так вот в нем, к моему удивлению, в модуле `Activity` есть подобные методы:

```
    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    MainMvpPresenter<MainMvpView> provideMainPresenter(
            MainPresenter<MainMvpView> presenter) {
        return presenter;
    }
```

А раз мы компонент активити создаем при `OnCreate()` :

```
 mActivityComponent = DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
            .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
            .applicationComponent(((MvpApp) getApplication()).getComponent())
            .build();
```

то выходит, что при переворачивании экрана, умрет и презентер. Ведь разумнее инстансы презентера основного активити привязать к жизни `application` ? 
Так почему провайдер презентера находится в активити модуле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина в том, что даггер 2 не используют для сохранения инстанса презентера (сохранение инстанса требуется, когда выполнился сетевой запрос и презентер должен принять ответ. Умирать вместе с активностью презентер не должен). Конечно можно сохранить в `AppComponent` инстанс презентера, но  возможно, когда мы покинем эту активность вовсе, и работаем уже на другой активности, то мы должны уничтожить презентер . написать presenter = null; Это дополнительная логика. выглядит криво. Для решения этой задачи используются retain фрагменты или фреймворк Moxy.